# VPN to work network from home

Tags: vpn

So we setup a VPN network for our staff to be able to remote in.  However, it is a separate network alongside the primary network.  How can we setup the VPN so it allows our workers to access everything as though it was onsite with the rest of the workstations?

Comment: You should set the Office end of the VPN to terminate in the IP address of the Office network and allow the subnet of the Office network to be accessed.  That is a normal way to connect

Comment: We are using unifi equipment. 

The primary network is setup as:
Gateway/Subnet: 192.168.1.1/24
Gateway IP: 192.168.1.1
Network Broadcast IP: 192.168.1.255
Network IP Count: 254
Network IP Range: 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254
Network Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

The VPN is setup as: 
Gateway/Subnet: 192.168.100.1/29
Network IP Count: 6
Network IP Range: 192.168.100.1 - 192.168.100.6

Are you suggesting I change the VPN to match the primary network's gateway/subnet?

Comment: If your main network is 192.168.1.x , then where is the VPN terminating?   IPsec VPN or PPTP?

Comment: It's a L2TP Server

Comment: So what address is the server and what is not connecting?

Comment: 192.168.100.1/29 is the L2TP server.  We can successfully connect to it, but we don't see any of the other workstations or printers that are on 192.168.1.1/24

Comment: You need to make the server address 192.168.1  not .100

Comment: So am I making it 192.168.1.1?  What about the subnet?

Comment: .1 (Third Octet) is the subnet. Did you set this up? or a Consultant?  Get the person who set if up to use 192.168.1.x as you have done and then set up the internal addressing

Comment: Using 192.168.1.1 causes an overlay error, and it wont take 192.168.1.x or *

Comment: You may need to move the VPN outside of your Windows Server to a VPN box. Either that, or bring in a consultant to assist you.

Comment: Something to consider is your local networks IP Range / subnet. If your home network is also on the IP Range 192.168.1.X this will get resolved locally and no traffic will go through the VPN. I had this issue before and reverted to changing my local network to 172.16.1.X/24 so that any request to the subnet 192.168.1.X would resolve through the VPN.

Comment: @LITS1337 Please add additional information not by adding comments but by editing your question.